# my computer is crashing and I think it is overheating

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, overheating

My computer is crashing lately with the colors on the display changing and the display not being updated (aside from the fact that I can see hints of mouse movement).

Originally I thought it might be software drivers but now I think it is overheating. I would like to measure the temperatures of both my CPU as well as my GForce display card. I need the display card since I have dual monitors (on a desktop computer).

I found the sensors program which gives:

```
ilan@ilan-main:~$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +37.0°C  (high = +76.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +31.0°C  (high = +76.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

f71889fg-isa-0a00
Adapter: ISA adapter
+3.3V:        +3.28 V  
in1:          +1.07 V  (max =  +2.04 V)
in2:          +1.10 V  
in3:          +0.94 V  
in4:          +0.69 V  
in5:          +0.54 V  
in6:          +0.40 V  
3VSB:         +3.30 V  
Vbat:         +3.18 V  
fan1:        1587 RPM
fan2:        1618 RPM
fan3:        1554 RPM
temp1:        +27.0°C  (high = +255.0°C, hyst = +251.0°C)
                       (crit = +255.0°C, hyst = +251.0°C)  sensor = transistor
temp2:        +39.0°C  (high = +255.0°C, hyst = +251.0°C)
                       (crit = +96.0°C, hyst = +92.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp3:        +41.0°C  (high = +255.0°C, hyst = +253.0°C)
                       (crit = +255.0°C, hyst = +253.0°C)  sensor = transistor

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +68.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +122.0°C, hyst =  +2.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
```

I see nouveau-pci-0100, whatever that is, is fairly hot. If it is the CPU or the display card, I simply don't know.

```
ilan@ilan-main:~$ nvidia-settings 

** (nvidia-settings:2924): WARNING **: PRIME: Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/prime-supported" (No such file or directory)
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

comes up with a Nvidia dialog with various information, but no obvious temperature. I don't know what prime supported means.

```
ilan@ilan-main:~$ nvclock -T
Error: You don't have enough permissions to run NVClock! Retry as root or install the Nvidia drivers.
*** stack smashing detected ***: nvclock terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

nvclock was supposed to give me the temperature but it crashes. I looked into installing the Nvidia drivers which it seems to indicate are not installed (even if I get the nvidia dialog from nvidia-settings.

In any case I tried to install the Xorg nvidia drivers and the system wanted to remove Wine. Wine I don't use very often, but once in a while I need it. Thus I didn't agree to install the Xorg nvidia drivers.

Comment: Thanks for the edits Sneetsher. Is there a help which shows how to do this formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to execute nvclock -T, first log in as root and then execute the command:

```
~$ sudo su
~# nvclock -T
```

Comment: I thought I had tried that. It does have an improvement: 'code' nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +74.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +122.0°C, hyst =  +2.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

ilan@ilan-main:~$ sudo nvclock -T
Xlib:  extension "NV-CONTROL" missing on display ":0".
nVidia Geforce 9300GS
=> GPU temperature: 75C
'code'. Note that nouveau-pci-0100 has a temperature within 1 degree. Are these the same things?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea. I personally never trust all these temperature sensors and software. To me overheating means one thing > buy better cooling system, a better fan, heat sink, etc..

Comment: Just to tell you that you are right. I bought some heat conduction material to make a better connection to the heat sink. Did it help? Of course not. In parallel I got some disk errors. Enough is enough, I bought a new computer.

Comment: hahaha, as you said these things happened in parallel and are not related to each other. I thought you are doing some heavy computation that causes heat, that's why I suggested a new cooling system, and by a new cooling system I meant with a new method such as cycling gas or liquid (like those ones people use in over-clocking competitions). On the other hand, if the computer is crappy at the first place I'm always in favour of buying a new one.
Have fun with your new computer.

Comment: Just in case someone else comes across the problem the nvclock and the PCI adapter in sensors are reporting the same thing. I tracked it after the computer was off for 2 hours and the numbers were always within 1 deg from each other.

Comment: Your giving me the sudo nvclock allowed me to confirm the fact. The computer is 4-5 years old and I need it compilations of c++ and java. My heaviest disply activity is displaying a movie. I suspect the crashes destroyed a couple of sectors on disk. In short, I don't spend new money to fix an old computer. I need something which works without giving me troubles.